# ElasticSearch Kibana version 7 not displaying dashboard because of browser security or other issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I believe there is something wrong with Kibana 7.0.1-linux-x86_64.  It will not not display the dashboard in the browser but will with curl using the public IP address.

If you open this URL it timeout http://ec2-35-180-186-122.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:5601/app/kibana .  But I know that Kibana is listening on that port because I can open it with curl (of course that's just to test it as curl cannot load the graphics).

At first I thought this was a browser issue.  As I got it to work with Chrome incognito and Safari.  But I could not get it working again.  So I started over and took the default configuration and only changed one item in kibana.yml to server.host: "172.31.46.15", so that it could be reached from the internet.

When I do curl

```
curl http://ec2-35-180-186-122.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:5601/app/kibana
```

it responds with this message showing that at least it is listening.

```
This Kibana installation has strict security requirements enabled that your current browser does not meet.
```

Kibana stdout says:

> {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-20T13:21:28Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":15611,"message":"Server
>   running at http://172.31.46.15:5601"}
>   {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-20T13:21:28Z","tags":["status","plugin:spaces@7.0.1","info"],"pid":15611,"state":"green","message":"Status
>   changed from yellow to green -
>   Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}

Comment: I see it is working for fine for people hitting my website as it is downloading graphics and such.  So it's just my latop that's not working.  I asked other people in this office to try too.  Could be in France they block this address.  They have national filters here to block porn.

Comment: never mind.  the port was blocked in the outbound direction from this office lan.

Comment: yes.  silly french thing.  they say this is because of GDPR requirements.